# Where Did Joshua 22 Take Place

Tags: joshua

When Joshua 'summomed the Reubenites, Gadites, and the half tribe of Manassheh', where did he summon them to?

Answer (score 2):

[Verse 9](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/study-bible/books/joshua/22/#v6022009) gives the answer:

> After that the Reuʹben·ites, the Gadʹites, and the half tribe of Ma·nasʹseh departed from the other Israelites, **from Shiʹloh in the land of Caʹnaan**, and they returned to the land of Gilʹe·ad, the land of their possession where they had settled at the order of Jehovah through Moses.

Answer (score 1):

Joshua 22:9 says they left the Israelites at Shiloh in Canaan.  Shiloh is just over 20 miles north of Jerusalem and about 10 miles south of Mount Gerizim.

Verse 10 says they came to Geliloth, near the Jordan.  My NIV Study Bible makes this comment:

> Geliloth - understood in the Septuagint to be Gilgal, next to Jericho.  It was probably a site east of Shiloh along the Jordan River.

Joshua 21:1-2 also sets the scene:

> Now the family heads of the Levites approached Eleazar the priest, Joshua sonon Nun, and the heads of the other tribal families of Israel at Shiloh in Canaan...